# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I try to execute a test and when I saving the tittle of the element my test fail.

Another example is -> title = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/section/aside/div/ul/li[2]/span').text
When I tried to print the title the prints is empty

Edit: I will add my code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
import unittest

class RS_firstTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_given_user_on_BO(self):
        driver = self.driver
         #Verify support icoon
        title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//[@id="root"]/section/aside/div/ul/li[2]/span').text
        self.assertEqual(title, 'List Support Tickets')
```

When I execute this one in console I see AssertionError: ' ' != 'List Support Tickets' .... my title is empty :(

Comment: Can you share the full code?

Comment: Yes!
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from time import sleep
import unittest

class RS_firstTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_given_user_on_BO(self):
        driver = self.driver
         #Login
        title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//[@id="root"]/section/aside/div/ul/li[2]/span').text
        self.assertEqual(title, 'List Support Tickets')

When I execute this one in console I see AssertionError: ' ' != 'List Support Tickets' .... my title is empty :(

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'RS_firstTestCase' object has no attribute 'driver'` error. Can you define the `driver` and edit the post?

Comment: I defined driver on
def setUp(self):
        s = Service('C:\dedge\msedgedriver.exe')
        self.driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s)
        self.driver.get('page.....')

I can't share the page :c

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify; code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead. While you edit... a [mcve] would be helpful, including the html of the page. If you can't share the whole page chip away the information that isn't relevant to your question (the m in [mcve]).